# Calculate price from two different table + using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables in my database, one table has trip/user related information: such as `trip_id`, `username`, `leave_date`, `return_date`, `flight_estimate`, `registration_fee` etc, and the second table is an expense table `trip_id` as my FK, and all the expenses such as hotelcost, bf,lunch for each date... so each `trip_ip` has more than one record in this table.

Now, I'm trying to create a summary table with total price using php for the user and when I used the following code, it gives the records of the trip with one date right, but if it has multiple dates, if creates two different records.. but I want it as one record (since I'm calculating grand total of that particular trip)

```
if(isset($user))
{
    $sql = 
          " SELECT Trip.trip_id as new_tripid"
        . "      , destination"
        . "      , leave_date"
        . "      , return_date"
        . "      , date(last_updatedate) as updateddate"
        . "      , flight_estimate"
        . "      , registration_fee"
        . "      , hotel_cost"
        . "      , breakfast_cost"
        . "      , lunch_cost"
        . "      , dinner_cost"
        . "      , parking_cost"
        . "      , taxi_cost"
        . "      , rental_car_cost"
        . "      , mileage"
        . "      , fuel_cost"
        . "      , other_cost"
        . "   FROM Trip"
        . "      , Expense"
        . "  WHERE Trip.username='" . $user ."'"
        . "    AND Trip.trip_id = Expense.trip_id"
    ;
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    $o = '<table id="myTable1" border="1" style="border:1px solid orange; background-color: #f3f3f3;"><thead><tr><th>Trip ID</th><th>Destination</th><th>Leave Date</th><th>Return Date</th><th>Total</th><th>Submit Date</th><th>Status</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

} else {
    echo('not valid user');
}

if (!$result) {
   die(mysql_error());
}

if ($num_rows<=0){
    echo('not valid user');
}
elseif ($num_rows>0)
{

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $grandtotoal = $row['flight_estimate'] + $row['registration_fee'] + 
                       $row['hotel_cost']+$row['breakfast_cost']+$row['lunch_cost']+
                       $row['dinner_cost']+$row['parking_cost']+$row['taxi_cost']+
                       $row['rental_car_cost'] +$row['mileage']+$row['fuel_cost']+$row['other_cost'];


        $o .= '<tr><td align = "center" style="width:absolute; height:30px;">'.
               $row['new_tripid'].'</td><td align = "center" style="width:absolute;height:30px;">'.
               $row['destination'].
               '</td><td align = "center" style="width:absolute height:30px;">'.
                $row['leave_date'].
                '</td><td align = "center" style="width:absolute; height:30px;">'.$row['return_date'].
                '</td><td align = "center" style="width:absolute; height:30px;">'.
                $grandtotoal.'</td><td align = "center" style="width:absolute; height:30px;">'.
                $row['updateddate'].'</td></tr>';
    }
    $o .= '</tbody></table>';

    echo $o;
}
```

Comment: have you considered trying MySQL SUM function to calculate the total expenses from the 2nd table ?

Comment: You need to learn about grouping and aggregate functions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function

Comment: You should use MySQLi or PDO instead of mysql_, mysql_ has been deprecated.

Comment: Outer joins are what solves this exact problem. If the right (expense) table has more records matching then you would use a right outer join.

Comment: Please consider switching from `mysql_*` to PDO for best performance and safer MySQL queries with PDO prepared statements

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.. I'm still in the learning process and appreciate your help and I will look into them! Will learn about grouping and aggregate..actually those are the ones that solved the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Trip.trip_id as new_tripid,destination, leave_date, return_date,
    date(last_updatedate) as updateddate, flight_estimate , registration_fee,
    SUM(hotel_cost, breakfast_cost, lunch_cost, dinner_cost, parking_cost, taxi_cost, 
    rental_car_cost, mileage, fuel_cost, other_cost) as total_cost
FROM Trip, Expense
WHERE Trip.username='$user' AND Trip.trip_id = Expense.trip_id
GROUP BY Trip.username
```

Comment: You need to group by for user, not for trip ;) (One user can have many trips)

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys.. ! I had to change GROUP BY to Trip.trip_id instead of trip.username and it worked.. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Thank you @Eleazan, Kirk Backus

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GRUOP BY` of MySQL:

```
SELECT Trip.trip_id as new_tripid,destination, leave_date, return_date,
    date(last_updatedate) as updateddate, flight_estimate , registration_fee,
    hotel_cost , breakfast_cost, lunch_cost,dinner_cost, parking_cost,taxi_cost,
    rental_car_cost, mileage , fuel_cost, other_cost
FROM Trip, Expense
WHERE Trip.username='$user' AND Trip.trip_id = Expense.trip_id
GROUP BY Trip.username
```